# Задний фон картинки ( css )

Tags: css

есть текст и картинка, когда хочу выделить текст выделяется почему то и сама картинка ( на скрине ниже ) возможно это связанно с неправильным позиционированием заднего фона, подскажите какой position ставить картинке заднего фона ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы просто выделяете не правильно захватывая и картинку. Да ещё картинку через HTML загрузили наверняка. Поэтому она и выделяется. а так можете этой картинке задать стиль "user-select: none;", только задайте именно картинке через знак ">", а то потом ещё будете думать, а что это не выделяется ничего.